# Echo in an if statement?

Tags: php

A very short question

how can i get this echo $Auth->if; to work in this if statement? i get no error when i run it but it dosen't seems to work at all? echo $Auth->id; show show the id number of the user logged in.

If i do for example `<?php echo $Auth->id; ?>` by itself it outputs the users id as it should.

```
if(($shortUrlDomain['premium_only'] != '0') && ($shortUrlDomain['premium_only'] != 'echo $Auth->id;'))
{
 continue;
}
```

Comment: What actually are you trying to do?

Comment: You should be getting an `unexpected T_ECHO` here, had you error reporting set.

Comment: Maybe he misunderstood. We should not judge him.

Comment: And when you think you’ve seen it all - SO to the rescue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `echo $Auth->id;'` by `$Auth->id` It won't work if you have an `echo` in your `if` also use `==` if `=` doesn't work.

```
if(($shortUrlDomain['premium_only'] !== '0') && ($shortUrlDomain['premium_only'] !==  $Auth->id))
    {
     continue;
    }
```

Comment: What did you do? What are we looking for that potentially solved their question?

Comment: I removed `'echo $Auth->id;'`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.
A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry.